# Is /ɑ/ of Standard Georgian realized as [ə]?

Tags: phonetics, allophones, georgian

On page 263 of this [PDF on Standard Georgian](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/A7DCF9606BA856FCA5CC25918ADB37EF/S0025100306002659a.pdf/standard_georgian.pdf), it shows a narrow transcription of the North Wind and the Sun as narrated by a native speaker of the Georgian language.

In that transcription, the phonetics of /ɛɣiɑɾɛbinɑ/ is [ɛɣiɑɾɛbinə]

Does it mean that /ɑ/ can be realized as [ə] in some contexts?

Comment: This phoneme in unstress environments is probably released as a schwa, it is pretty common, especially when they occur in the end of words in post tonic positions.